# Generating strings but it isnt working and its saying defined even though it is

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I keep on getting undefined on the result and I do not know why anyone able to help?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("key")
  .setDescription("Gives a key"),
  async execute(interaction, length) {
    const result = "";
    const characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (const i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    console.log("Command starting - key");
    await interaction.deferReply({
      fetchReply: true,
    });

    const newMessage = `**Here is your key:** ${result}`;
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: newMessage,
    });
  },
};
```

https://prnt.sc/BVQ9l8NR_JaR "what it says when I run it"

Comment: Use `let` to declare `i` in the for-loop, not `const`. This should be throwing a TypeError.

Comment: Please add the [tag:discord.js] tag and include the screenshot as part of the question instead of linking it so people can more easily understand the context.

Comment: @chazsolo I did that but I am still getting nothing

Comment: what is the output on the console? your screenshot is ui?

Comment: @irous I dont get any errors in the console.

Comment: if the console shows the `result` value, you're probably not calling your function properly. Can you show your calling code? Did you use `await execute()`?

Comment: @irous no thats all my code

Comment: What is `length`? Seems like it's `0`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Well yes and I just am clueless to what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Do you run this `execute` function somehow or does discord do it for you? Is there any documentation of that function?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Discord does it for you, but you just have to define it and make it work which from what I believe. I am positive I have.

Comment: I don't see any usage of this function with the second argument on the internet.  What does this `length` is supposed to do?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Well I removed length since it was already being used

Comment: You probably wanted to use `charactersLength ` in the loop

Comment: @KonradLinkowski its already declared

Comment: @KonradLinkowski If I run it all it says is length is not defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("key")
  .setDescription("Gives a key"),
  async execute(interaction) {
    let result = "";
    const characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < charactersLength; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    console.log("Command starting - key");
    await interaction.deferReply({
      fetchReply: true,
    });

    const newMessage = `**Here is your key:** ${result}`;
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: newMessage,
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: I tried that and it said `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable`

Comment: Forgot about this one `const`, check it now

Comment: `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` 

Still getting the same error at line 13:14

Comment: Another const to fix

Comment: Finally worked, thanks!